# SQL query to get at least one common item

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables which are,

`room  (room_no`)

`room_no_access (room_no, user_id`)

`user (user_id`)

If a user is recorded in `room_no_access` table with a `room_no` and `user_id` then that user cannot access the mentioned room.

Let's assume that I am a user in `user` table. Now what I need is to get the users who shares at least one common room access with me.

How to write a SQL to get this done? It's better if there are no loops in it.

Example:

```
rooms

room_1,
room_2,
room_3,

users

1,
2,
3,
4,

rooms_no_access

    [room_1, 4],
    [room_2, 3].
    [room_3, 3],
    [room_1, 3],
```

If I'm user 4 -> I have access to room_2, room_3
So who are the other users who has access to room_2 or room_3
They are ->1,2

Comment: So you want a list of users that what they have in common is at least one room NOT in room_no_access with the users id?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Seems like you are missing one important table here room with access

Comment: It sounds like you want something really simple, like SELECT user_id from room_no_access WHERE room_no = your_room_no, but I'm guessing that's not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: no. I don't have a specific room number

Comment: here we don't use a table for room with access. it only uses a room_no_access. Those are the only ones restricted.

Comment: i guess he need , user id 's with count >1 when its grouped by room_no from room_no_access table

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks for the every ones support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of back to front, as you hold which rooms people DON'T have access to, and we really want rooms people DO have access to.

I created some test data:

```
--Test data
DECLARE @room TABLE (room_no INT);
INSERT INTO @room SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
DECLARE @user TABLE ([user_id] INT);
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
DECLARE @room_no_access TABLE (room_no INT, [user_id] INT);
INSERT INTO @room_no_access SELECT 1, 1;
INSERT INTO @room_no_access SELECT 3, 2;
INSERT INTO @room_no_access SELECT 1, 3;
INSERT INTO @room_no_access SELECT 2, 3;
INSERT INTO @room_no_access SELECT 3, 3;
```

...and then came up with this query:

```
--For each user find users with common access
--First find which rooms each user can access
WITH room_access AS (
    SELECT
        r.room_no,
        u.[user_id]
    FROM
        @room r
        CROSS JOIN @user u
        LEFT JOIN @room_no_access rn ON rn.room_no = r.room_no AND rn.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
    WHERE
        rn.[user_id] IS NULL)
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.[user_id],
    sa.[user_id] AS shared_access_user
FROM
    @user u
    LEFT JOIN room_access ra ON ra.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
    LEFT JOIN room_access sa ON sa.room_no = ra.room_no
WHERE
    sa.[user_id] != u.[user_id]; --Ignore self match
```

That's a little long-winded for the job, but it's easy to follow.

Results are:

```
user_id shared_access_user
1   2
2   1
```

Because in my data user_id #1 and #2 share access to room #2, but user_id #3 has no access to any rooms.

I am returning the results for each user in the database, but you could filter this to only return results for a specified user?

Comment: Yes. I need for a specific user. Anyway this works for me. Thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct [user_id] from (
    --all rooms that can be accessed by at least one user
    select room_no, [USER_ID] from room cross join [user]
    except
    select room_no, [USER_ID] from room_no_access
) a where room_no in (
    -- rooms that I have access to
    select room_no from room
    except
    select room_no from room_no_access where [USER_ID] = /*my_user_id*/
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This select users that share access with you and the rooms they shares.

```
set @you = 1;

select 
    others_access.user_id, 
    others_access.room_no
from 
  (select room_no, @you as user_id 
  from room r
  /* rooms that you have access */
  where not exists (
    select * from room_no_access rna
    where rna.room_no = r.room_no
    and rna.user_id = @you)) you_access
join  
  /* rooms that others have access */
  (select room_no, u.user_id
  from room r cross join user u
  where u.user_id <> @you
  and not exists (
    select * from room_no_access rna
    where rna.room_no = r.room_no
    and rna.user_id = u.user_id)) others_access
on you_access.room_no = others_access.room_no;
```

[Here a DB Fiddle to play with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/awiMxwED8t7HKbFv5GS9dJ/0)